# Why am I getting "invalid conversion from 'Queue*/Stack*' to 'int'" error message?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14, c++17

Why am I getting these errors?

> invalid conversion from 'Queue*' to 'int'

> conversion from 'Stack*' to non-scalar type 'Stack' requested

I've tried modifying `Queue` & `Stack`, but to no avail. I am doing an assignment that implements `Stack` using `Queue`s & implements `Queue` using `Stack`s.

**Stack.h**

```
#ifndef STACK_H_
#define STACK_H_
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Stack {
    int size;
    int capacity; // for dynamic allocated array
    int stackTop;
    int *arr;

public:
    Stack();
    void push(int val);
    int pop();
    bool isFull();
    bool empty();
    int top();
    int peek(int pos);
    int resize();
};

bool Stack::empty(){
    return size == 0;
}

bool Stack::isFull(){
    return size == capacity;
}

void Stack::push(int val){

    if(isFull())
        resize();

    arr[++stackTop] = val;
    size++;
}

int Stack::pop(){

    if(empty())
        return true;

    return arr[stackTop--];

}

int Stack::peek(int pos){

    if(pos > stackTop || pos < 0){
        cout << "Empty Stack";
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return arr[size - pos - 1];
    }
}

int Stack::top(){

    if(empty()){
        return true;
    }

    return *arr;

}

int Stack::resize(){

    return size;
}
```

**Queue.h**

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H_
#define QUEUE_H_
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Queue{

    int f, r, *arr, size, capacity;

public:

    Queue(): f(-1), r(-1), arr(nullptr), size(0), capacity(0){}
    Queue(int cap): f(-1), r(-1), arr(new int[cap]), size(0), capacity(cap){}
    ~Queue(){delete []arr;}

    Queue(const Queue &copy){

        f = copy.f;
        r = copy.r;
        arr = copy.arr;
        size = copy.size;
        capacity = copy.capacity;
    }

    Queue(Queue&& move){

        f = move.f;
        r = move.r;
        arr = move.arr;
        size = move.size;
        capacity = move.capacity;

        move.f = -1;
        move.r = -1;
        move.arr = nullptr;
        move.size = 0;
        move.capacity = 0;
    }

    Queue& operator=(const Queue& copyA){

        if(this == &copyA){

            return *this;
        }

        f = copyA.f;
        r = copyA.r;
        arr = copyA.arr;
        size = copyA.size;
        capacity = copyA.capacity;
    }

    Queue& operator=(const Queue&& moveA){

        if(this == &moveA){

            return *this;
        }

        f = moveA.f;
        r = moveA.r;
        arr = moveA.arr;
        size = moveA.size;
        capacity = moveA.capacity;

//      moveA.f = -1;
//      moveA.r = -1;
//      moveA.arr = nullptr;
//      moveA.size = 0;
//      moveA.capacity = 0;

        return *this;
    }

    void enqueue(int x){
        if(!full())
            resize();
        arr[f + r] = x;
        size++;
    }


    int dequeue(){
        if(!empty()){
            return arr[++f];
        } return -99999;
    }

    bool empty(){
        return size == 0;
    }

    bool full(){
        return size == capacity;
    }

    int peek(int pos){

        if(pos > capacity || pos < 0){
            cout << "Empty Queue";
            return 0;
        }else{
            return arr[size - pos - 1];
        }
    }

    void resize(){
        int newSize = this->size * 2;
        Queue *temp = new Queue[newSize];
        int count = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i){
            int index = (f + 1) % size;
            temp[i] = arr[index];
        }
    }
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Queue.h"
#include "Stack.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){

    Queue q = new Queue(); //invalid conversion from 'Queue*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]

    q.enqueue(1);
    q.enqueue(2);
    q.enqueue(3);

    cout << q.dequeue() << '\n';
    cout << q.dequeue() << '\n';
    cout << q.dequeue() << '\n';

    cout << endl;

    Stack s = new Stack(); //conversion from 'Stack*' to non-scalar type 'Stack' requested
    s.push(1);
    s.push(2);
    s.push(3);

    cout << "current size: " << s.resize() << endl;
    cout << s.top() << endl;

    s.pop();

    cout << s.top() << endl;

    s.pop();

    cout << s.top() << endl;

    cout << "current size: " << s.resize() << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

```
    
main.cpp:8:12: error: invalid conversion from 'Queue*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
  Queue q = new Queue();
            ^~~~~~~~~~~

20:12: error: conversion from 'Stack*' to non-scalar type 'Stack' requested
  Stack s = new Stack();
            ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: `if(empty()) return true` in functions `int pop()` and `int top()`. didn't go through everything but these two are definitely incorrect

Comment: @mangusta Please explain how.

Comment: @mangusta Well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error would come from the line in **main.cpp**:

```
Queue q = new Queue();
```

The `new` keyword creates a pointer to the class object, so the correct syntax would be:

```
Queue *q = new Queue();
```

This is also shown in the C++ tutorial documentation here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/#pointers_to_classes

Same thing for the `Stack` pointer variable.

Note that this also means the syntax for using the objects must also change.

Instead of:

```
s.pop();
```

You will need to modify this to either:

```
(*s).pop();
```

or

```
s->pop();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also, in reference to what @mangusta mentioned. (Can't comment due to new reputation):

The definition of the class functions `pop()` and `top()` specify a return type of `int`. However, as mention by @mangusta, if `empty()` returns `true`, this would violate the specified return type, since it would be trying to return a `bool` rather than an `int`.

Comment: that is a *logic* error though, not a *code* error. The C++ language has well-defined implicitly conversions from `bool` to `int` and vice versa. If the stack is empty, there is nothing to return, so the code should throw an exception instead of confusing the caller by returning a value that could have been stored in the stack had it not been empty.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's a great point, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Additionally, the reason the error is about a conversion, is because the single argument constructor ("Queue(int cap)") is trying to do such a conversion.  Its frequently a good idea for single argument constructors to be declared with the explicit keyword unless you intend for them to be used for conversion.

Comment: @EvanGiarta Now the program is crashing. :(

Comment: @WolfAngleBlade What's the error? Where line is it crashing at? If you absolutely do not need to use pointers, the answer from acraig5075 may be the better way to go.

Comment: @EvanGiarta That still did not solve the crashing issue.

Comment: @WolfAngleBlade Well, without more information, I guess this MIGHT be the issue:

    cout << "current size: " << s->resize() << endl;

resize function returns void, but you are expecting a variable (likely a string) here. Output size instead and typecast to string.

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate with the `new` keyword, you create a pointer to the object. Thus, the correct instantiation would be the following:

```
Queue * q = new Queue();

Stack * s = new Stack();
```

When `x` is a pointer, then the value of `x` is the address of an object and `*x` is the actual object.

Comment: Now the program is crashing. :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree with the answers advising getting it to work with `new`. It's unnecessary.

Instead of using `new` just leave them as normal stack variables. Then you're not burdened with having to later `delete` and you don't have to replace all instances of `.` to `->`.

Simply

```
Queue q;
Stack s;
```

And your program remains otherwise unchanged.

(Do you perhaps come from a [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) background? `new` is necessary there, but most often not necessary with C++)